# Marionette CompositeView: Uncaught ItemViewContainerMissingError: The specified `itemViewContainer` was not found:

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

Have this weird error while using Marionette's CompositeView:

```
Marionette CompositeView: Uncaught ItemViewContainerMissingError: The specified `itemViewContainer` was not found: tbody
```

The element that is not found `tbody` is in the template. I've looked over the rest of my project and I've done the same thing over many times without a problem. It must be something small that I am missing.

Is there a particular anti-pattern that is associated with this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the past when I have run into this error, it was caused by rendering the view before it was shown onto the page.

Specifically, I reset the collection, which caused the view to re-render before I had displayed it on the page.

Comment: Is there a good work around? I'm running into this issue with a layout view that has a collection view with filters as item views, when changing the filters the collectionview is then re-rendered but it seems sometimes the load is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. My problem was that the `itemViewContainer`(`ul`, in my case) wasn't in the main div.

I had this code before:

```
<div class="row page-width">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<img src="assets/images/help.png" width="35" height="35" alt="help">
<strong> Help</strong>
</div>
</div>
<div><ul class="main-tabs"></ul></div>
```

So changing it to be included in the main div, solved it for me:

```
<div class="row page-width">
<div class="large-12 columns">
<img src="assets/images/help.png" width="35" height="35" alt="help">
<strong> Help</strong>
</div>
<ul class="main-tabs"></ul></div>
```